# Get original creation time for all excel files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a folder containing many excel files and extract the file name and creation time to a text file. By creation time, I mean the time the file was originally created rather than the time it was created on my system.

The following code works, but gives me the wrong time. I think `FileDateTime` is the wrong command, but after an hour of desperate googling I haven't been able to find the correct one.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
Sub CheckFileTimes()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim thisBook As String
    Dim creationDate As Date
    Dim outputText As String
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
    Dim fso, f

'set up output file
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\TEST.txt", ForWriting, True)

'open folder and loop through
    StrFile = Dir("c:\HW\*.xls*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
'get creation date
       creationDate = FileDateTime("C:\HW\" & StrFile)
'get filename
       thisBook = StrFile
       outputText = thisBook & "," & creationDate
'write to output file
       f.writeLine outputText
'move to next file in folder
       StrFile = Dir
    Loop
    f.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I found the answer. Looks like I wasn't too far off (though I don't think this is anywhere near optimal). Thanks to everyone who took a look at this.

```
Sub CheckFileTimes3()
    Dim StrFile, thisBook, outputText As String
    Dim creationDate As Date
    Dim fso, f
    Dim oFS As Object
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'open txt file for storing results
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\TEST.txt", ForWriting, True)

    'loop through all files in given folder
    StrFile = Dir("c:\HW\*.xls*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
       Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\HW\" & StrFile
       creationDate = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")
       thisBook = StrFile
       outputText = thisBook & "," & creationDate
       'MsgBox outputText
       f.writeLine outputText
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       StrFile = Dir
    Loop
    f.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateCreated` with the `FileSystemObject`.

A small tweak to your current code does this

I have tided up the the variables as well

```
Sub CheckFileTimes()
Dim StrFile As String
Dim StrCDate As Date
Dim fso As Object
Dim f As Object

'set up output file
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.OpentextFile("C:\TEST.txt", 2, True)

'open folder and loop through
    StrFile = Dir("c:\HW\*.xls*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set objFile = fso.getfile("c:\HW\" & StrFile)
'get creation date
       StrCDate = objFile.datecreated
'write to output file
       f.writeLine StrFile & "," & StrCDate
'move to next file in folder
       StrFile = Dir
    Loop
    f.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's still giving me the wrong time though.

After a bit more research, it looks like I need to use `BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")`, but this object doesn't support it. 

Do you know of any way to apply it?

Comment: Actually `BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")`gives the template creation date -not the workbook creation date

Comment: There is a good explanation here - see http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip57.htm.